# How to differentiate between background color and text color?

Tags: java, pdfbox

can anyone help me how to differentiate between background color and text color of pdf document if background color and text color are same.

Actually I need to set some static color to invisible text
using pdfbox so that text which are invisible we can see.

TextObjectInfo contains all text object information using PDFStreamEngine .

```
public class SimplePdfRegeneretor {
    private PDDocument _document;
    private PDResources _pageResource;
    private PDFTextObjectInfoExtraction _PDFTextObjectInfoExtraction;
    private List<List<TextObjectInfo>> _documentTextObjectInfo;
    
    private void RecreatePDF() throws IOException{
        int _pageNo = 0;
        for (PDPage page : _document.getPages())
        {
            List<TextObjectInfo> _pageTextObjectInfo = this._documentTextObjectInfo.get(_pageNo);
             try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(_document,
                    page, AppendMode.APPEND, false, true)){
                    Integer _textObjInfoInx = 0 ;
                    //contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0,0,0,0);
                    for(TextObjectInfo _textObjInfo : _pageTextObjectInfo){  
                    Float _xmin = _textObjInfo.get_xyminmax().get(0);
                    Float _ymin = _textObjInfo.get_xyminmax().get(1); 
                    putTextOnDocument(contentStream,_textObjInfo,_textObjInfo.TextFontObject,_xmin,_ymin,_textObjInfoInx);
                    _textObjInfoInx++; 
               }
               
            }
            _pageNo++;
        }

        _pageNo = 0;
        for (PDPage _page : _document.getPages())
            {
                List<Object> newTokens = addTjStringtoContenStream(_page,_pageNo);
                PDStream newContents = new PDStream(_document);
                writeTokensToStream(newContents, newTokens);
                _page.setContents(newContents);
                System.out.println("Page TextObject Writting Completed.."+_pageNo);
                _pageNo++;
            }

    }
    
    private void putTextOnDocument(PDPageContentStream contentStream, TextObjectInfo _textObjInfo, PDFont font, Float horizontalPixel, 
                                                                   Float verticalPixel, int TextObjectIndex) throws IOException {
        
        String _textobjstr = "TextObjectIndex-" + TextObjectIndex;
        Matrix _tm = _textObjInfo.textMatrixs.get(_textObjInfo.textMatrixs.size()-1);
        int fontSize = _textObjInfo.TextFontSize.intValue();
        PDGraphicsState _GraphicsState = _textObjInfo.getGraphicsState();
        PDTextState _TextState = _GraphicsState.getTextState();
        
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(_GraphicsState.getNonStrokingColor());
        contentStream.setStrokingColor(_GraphicsState.getStrokingColor());
        contentStream.setRenderingMode(_TextState.getRenderingMode());
        contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
        contentStream.setTextMatrix(_tm);
        contentStream.beginMarkedContent(COSName.getPDFName(_textobjstr));
        contentStream.endMarkedContent();
        contentStream.endText();
    }

    private List<Object> addTjStringtoContenStream(PDContentStream contentStream, int _pgInx) throws IOException{
        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contentStream);
        Object token = parser.parseNextToken();
        List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<>();
        List<TextObjectInfo> _pageTextObjInfo =  this._documentTextObjectInfo.get(_pgInx);
        System.out.println("Len of _pageTextObjInfo: "+_pageTextObjInfo.size());
        //newTokens.add(Operator.getOperator("q"));
        while (token != null)
        {
            if (token instanceof Operator)
            {
                Operator op = (Operator) token;
                String opName = op.getName();
                if (OperatorName.BEGIN_MARKED_CONTENT.equals(opName))
                {
                    // remove the argument to this operator
                    //System.out.println(newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1));
                    Integer _tjObjInx = Integer.parseInt(((COSName)newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1)).getName().replace("TextObjectIndex-", ""));
                    
                    TextObjectInfo _TextObjectInfo = _pageTextObjInfo.get(_tjObjInx);
                    COSString _tjStr = _TextObjectInfo.TjString;
                    newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);
                    newTokens.add(_tjStr);
                    newTokens.add(Operator.getOperator("Tj"));
                    token = parser.parseNextToken();
                    continue;
                }
                else if (OperatorName.END_MARKED_CONTENT.equals(opName))
                {
                    token = parser.parseNextToken();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            newTokens.add(token);
            token = parser.parseNextToken();
        }
        //newTokens.add(Operator.getOperator("Q"));
        return newTokens;
    }
    private static void writeTokensToStream(PDStream newContents, List<Object> newTokens) throws IOException
    {
        try (OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE))
        {
            ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
            writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
        }
    }
}
```

1.this is background image
[image]

2.this is text having black color without background image
[image]

3.this is input document where text is visible
[image]

4.and this is output where text is invisible i.e Silver
[image]

Comment: Put a code snippet and exact api that you are using for pdfbox.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to achieve? As far as I understand you, you want text color equal background color, so that the text is not visible. In that case, though, why don't you simply draw the text using the rendering mode "Invisible"? That would add the text to the document (to search for and to copy&paste) without being visible.

Comment: Hi @mkl I want output like source document image. But in our case text is invisible. How can I make it visible.

Comment: How about drawing all text with an outline whose color differs from its fill color?

Comment: @mkl can you please suggest me with some code snippet using example.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure: As input you have a document in which there is text that is invisible because it is drawn in the same color as its background (and not e.g. because it is later covered by something, or because the font only has empty glyphs, or because rendering mode "invisible" is used). And the output should be a copy of the document in which that text is visible. Your original idea was to somehow check for each bit of text whether its color differs from the background and otherwise change its color to make it differ from the background. And my visible-outline approach would be ok, too.